# define webpack internal paths to debug site with two bundles with similar file structures

Tags: debugging, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I have a site that is using multiple independent webpack bundles, which all have roughly the same file structure. When I try to debug something in chrome devtools, it looks like modules are interefering with eachother on the debug level, since both use paths like `webpack:///./src/index.ts`, hence I'm only able to view the index.ts file of the last module loaded.

Is there a way to add a prefix or otherwise regulate the internal paths webpack is using? So that it becomes something like `webpack:///[mymodulename]/src/index.ts`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the following makes sure source maps use a relative filepath, and in this way I'm able to append something to it, so now I can debug each bundle individually again

```
output: {
    filename: "./bundle_a.js",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "bundle_a/[resource-path]"
},
```